# Addition of Variable values is Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I am trying to perform addition operation in freemarker but not able to get a result.
Testing the FTL works well but no output is obtained.

```
      <#if REFDATA.get("100."+item["100"]!"")?string?has_content>
 <#assign cc= REFDATA.get("100."+item["100"]?number?string("0.########")!"")>
    <#else>
     <#assign cc=item["100"]!"">             
     </#if> 
          <#if cn=="T1"> 
        ${REFDATA.put(c1,cc!"")} 
         </#if>
          <#if cn=="T2"> 
        ${REFDATA.put(c2,cc!"")} 
         </#if>
          <#if cn=="T3"> 
        ${REFDATA.put(c3,cc!"")} 
         </#if>
         <#if cn=="T4"> 
        ${REFDATA.put(c4,cc!"")} 
             </#if>                         
        <#assign cAdd=(c1 + c2 + c3 + c4)!"">
```

Thanks,
CK

Comment: What are `c1,c2,c3,c4`? either one of them is null or you just don't do anything with `cAdd`

Comment: each of them has values..not sure if the addition syntax is correct - 
 <#assign cAdd=(c1 + c2 + c3 + c4)!"">

Comment: It's correct, if might do something else if they are not numbers but if it's possible it will assign the addition to `cAdd` or an empty string if there was a problem.

Comment: i am converting them to number from string-                                              
<#if REFDATA.get("100."+item["100"]!"")?string?has_content>
 <#assign cc= REFDATA.get("100."+item["100"]?number!"")>

Comment: where do you assign anything to them?

Comment: What you (try to) do here is business logic and does not belong in template (freemarker). Should be done in Model or Controller.

Comment: Thanks..Taking care of it in Controller makes the functionality more stable.